# Dedekind Cut for $\sqrt{2}$ and Hardy's Proof

Tags: real-analysis

To show that the lower class of rationals for the cut to represent $\sqrt{2}$ contains no greatest element and the upper class of rationals for the cut to represent $\sqrt{2}$ contains no smallest element, Hardy wrote in the section $4$ of the first chapter of his book *[A Course of Pure Mathematics](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/38769/38769-pdf.pdf)* that

> Let us consider more closely the equation $x^2 = 2$.
>
> We have already seen that there is no rational number $x$ which
> satisfies this equation. The square of any rational number is either
> less than or greater than $2$. We can therefore divide the rational
> numbers into two classes, one containing the numbers whose squares are
> less than $2$, and the other those whose squares are greater than $2$.
> We shall confine our attention to the positive rational numbers, and
> we shall call these two classes the class $L$, or the lower class, or
> the left-hand class, and the class $R$, or the upper class, or the
> right-hand class. It is obvious that every member of $R$ is greater
> than all the members of $L$. Moreover it is easy to convince ourselves
> that we can find a member of the class $L$ whose square, though less
> than $2$, differs from $2$ by as little as we please, and a member of
> $R$ whose square, though greater than $2$, also differs from $2$ by as
> little as we please...
>
> We can supply a formal proof as follows. In the first place, we can
> find a member of $L$ and a member of $R$, differing by as little as we
> please. For we saw in section $3$ that, given any two rational numbers
> $a$ and $b$, we can construct a chain of rational numbers, of which
> $a$ and $b$ are the first and last, and in which any two consecutive
> numbers differ by as little as we please. Let us then take a member
> $x$ of $L$ and a member $y$ of $R$, and interpolate between them a
> chain of rational numbers of which $x$ is the first and $y$ the last,
> and in which any two consecutive numbers differ by less than $\delta$,
> $\delta$ being any positive rational number as small as we please,
> such as $.01$ or $.0001$ or $.000 001$. In this chain there must be a
> last which belongs to $L$ and a first which belongs to $R$, and these
> two numbers differ by less than $δ$.
>
> We can now prove that an $x$ can be found in $L$ and a $y$ in $R$ such
> that $2−x^2$ and $y^2-2$ are as small as we please, say less than
> $\delta$. Substituting $\frac{1}{4}\delta$ for $\delta$ in the
> argument which precedes, we see that we can choose $x$ and $y$ so that
> $y - x < \frac{1}{4}\delta$; and we may plainly suppose that both $x$
> and $y$ are less than $2$. Thus $$y + x < 4, y^2 − x^2 = (y − x)(y + x) < 4(y − x) < δ;$$ and since $x^2 < 2$ and $y^2 > 2$ it follows a
> fortiori that $2 − x^2$ and $y^2-2$ are each less than $\delta$.
>
> It follows also that there can be no largest member of $L$ or smallest
> member of $R$. For if $x$ is any member of $L$, then $x^2 < 2$.
> Suppose that $x^2 = 2 − δ$. Then we can find a member $x_1$ of $L$
> such that $x_1^2$ differs from $2$ by less than $δ$, and so $x_1^2 > x^2$ or $x_1 > x$. Thus there are larger members of $L$ than $x$; and
> as $x$ is any member of $L$, it follows that no member of $L$ can be
> larger than all the rest. Hence $L$ has no largest member, and
> similarly $R$ has no smallest.

Could you please explain why we may plainly suppose that both $x$ and $y$ are less than $2$? What's the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 2):

$x$ and $y$ are chosen from the lower and upper sets $L$ and $R$ respectively.
Since $x^2 < 2$ it's clear that $x < 2$. Since $(3/2)^2 > 2$, we know $3/2$ is in $R$ and is less than $2$. If the $y$ in Hardy's argument were bigger than $3/2$ we could replace it by $3/2$ and the rest of the argument would work with no change.

Answer (score 0):

What Hardy is trying to show is that $L$ has no greatest element, and $R$ has no smallest element. So, his argument goes by assuming $x$ and $y$ in $L$ and $R$, and constructing new elements $x_1$ and $y_1$ in $L$ and $R$ such that;
$x_1>x\text{ and }y_1<y.$

So, since are assuming that $x$ and $y$ are the respective greatest and smallest elements of $L$ and $R$, we can easily argue that they have to be smaller than $2$ and greater than $1$, otherwise we can give $1.1$ and $1.9$ and counterexamples to attain contradiction.

It follows because of the nature of our extremal argument.

[image]